# How to see the commands echoed on the Terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line

Maybe is a silly question but I'm a newbie in OS X and I didn't found the answer anywhere. The thing is that when I execute some command that executes other scripts/commands/whatever I don't see on the terminal exactly what the commands did, just the title on the terminal window changes. E.g. when I run `make` to compile a c++ program there are different executables involved (clang, xcodebuild ...) I know that those commands are being executed because I see their names changing in the title, but I don't know how was the original call (in other words, the arguments given) or the output (if any). Any ideas?

Comment: No answers at all? Maybe this means it is not possible to see the commands? Maybe was designed that way, but don't understand why...

Comment: All you see on the Terminal window is the standard output, what you're asking is to see standard input. Kinda redundant... May I ask why you want to do this?